# How to judge the key word by if in awk?

Tags: shell, awk

I have a job information file which is named tmpInfo.txt in my project.
The content of tmpInfo.txt is like:

```
875675 mpirun -machinefile $PBS_NODEFILE -np $NP /opt/software/vasp/vasp-intel/vasp5.4/vasp5.4.1/vasp_std>o.$PBS_JOBID.out
875676 mpirun -machinefile $PBS_NODEFILE -np $NP /opt/software/vasp/vasp-intel/vasp5.4/vasp5.4.1/vasp_std>o.$PBS_JOBID.out
875683 source /opt/software/Gaussian/g09-env.sh
875695 
875696 
875697 EXEC=/home/inspur/tensorflow_test/test.py python3 $EXEC
875698 /opt/intel/impi/5.0.2.044/intel64/bin/mpirun -machinefile $PBS_NODEFILE -n 480 /opt/software/vasp/vasp-intel/vasp5.4/vasp5.4.1/vasp_gam
875699 fluent 3d -g -t$proc -mpi=intel -ssh -cnf=conf_file -i aircraft_wing_2m.commands
875764 source /opt/software/Gaussian/g09-env.sh /opt/software/Gaussian/g09/g09 <Bush_2_b_fix1a_1_fre_ts1a3_irc_r_opt1_sccc_fix1_ts_irc_r_opt_fsc.gjf>> "Bush_2_b_fix1a_1_fre_ts1a3_irc_r_opt1_sccc_fix1_ts_irc_r_opt_fsc.log"
```

Now i want to get conclusion according to the key words for each rows;

I have tred:

```
awk '{if ($0=~"Gaussian") print $0" "gaussion; else if ($0=~"fluent") print $0" "fluent; else print $0" "NKOWN}' tmpInfo.txt
```

But unlucky, I got error information:

```
awk: {if ($0=~"Gaussian") print $0" "gaussion; else if ($0=~"fluent") print $0" "fluent; else print "C"}
awk:         ^ syntax error
awk: {if ($0=~"Gaussian") print $0" "gaussion; else if ($0=~"fluent") print $0" "fluent; else print "C"}
awk:                                           ^ syntax error
awk: {if ($0=~"Gaussian") print $0" "gaussion; else if ($0=~"fluent") print $0" "fluent; else print "C"}
awk:                                                       ^ syntax error
awk: {if ($0=~"Gaussian") print $0" "gaussion; else if ($0=~"fluent") print $0" "fluent; else print "C"}
awk:
```

it seems nothing wrong, who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do 2 major changes in your code. 1st change `=~`(it is used in shell and `awk` is not shell) to `~/string/` then I am considering that `gaussion` is a text you want to print in output so wrap it too in `"gaussion"` same applies to other texts too.

Try following once.

```
awk '{if($0~/Gaussian/){print $0" gaussion"} else if($0~/fluent/){print $0" fluent"} else{print $0" UNKOWN"}}'  Input_file
```

Or a non-one liner form of solution as follows.

```
awk '
{
  if($0~/Gaussian/){
     print $0" gaussion"
  }
  else if($0~/fluent/){
     print $0" fluent"
  }
  else{
     print $0" UNKOWN"
  }
}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have lines where both Gaussian and fluent appear and you don't really want to mis-spell gaussian in your output, I'd do it as this with GNU awk:

```
awk '{print $0, (match{$0,/Gaussian|fluent/,a) ? tolower(a[0]) : "UNKNOWN")}'  Input_file
```

or with any awk:

```
awk '{print $0, (match{$0,/Gaussian|fluent/) ? tolower(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)) : "UNKNOWN")}'  Input_file
```